# Regular Expression in Node.js Express Router

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I have tried to find a way to enter regular expression into an express routing URL and then access the variable portion of the URL through the request object. Specifically I want to route to the url "/posts/" + any number of digits. Is there a way to do this?

Examples:

```
/posts/54
/posts/2
/posts/546
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do it:

```
app.get('/posts/:id(\\d+)', function(req, res) {
    // id portion of the request is available as req.params.id
});
```

**EDIT**: added regex to path to limit it to digits

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Johnny, my only addition being that you can do this for any number of levels. For example:

```
app.get('/users/:id/:karma', function(req, res){
    //Both req.params.id and req.params.karma are available parameters.
});
```

You should also check out the express documentation: http://expressjs.com/api.html.
The request section would probably prove quite useful to you.