# How to match an express route using a positive integer regex?

Tags: regex, node.js, express

This should actually be a fairly easy question, but for some reason I can't get it to work.

I'm using Node.js along with Express's router.  I'm trying to capture a url like below:

```
http://localhost:3000/items/2
http://localhost:3000/items/35
```

I've got the following regex expressions.  The '2' route works, but the '35' does not and I'm not sure why.

```
router.get('/items/:id([0-9])', function(req, res){
    console.log("I work for /items/2");
});

router.get('/items/:id(^[0-9]*$)', function(req, res){
    console.log("I don't work at all :(");
});
```

The second route's regex works just fine when I test against https://regex101.com/#javascript.  I also tried the regex ^\d+$ which works at regex101 but not in node.

Am I missing something obvious?  Using "express": "^4.13.3" in my package.json.

** Update **

I used the regex's answer from this post to make it work: [Regular Expression in Node.js Express Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123564/regular-expression-in-node-js-express-router)

```
router.get('/items/:id(\\d+)', function(req, res) {
    console.log('I work!');
});
```

However, even when I added an additional '\' to make '^\\d+$', the route still didn't catch '25'.

** Update **

Looks like if I take off the regex anchors, '^' & '$', the routes work, but I don't understand why that would be.

Comment: Any particular reason for the down votes?  This seems like a pretty detailed question.

Comment: Think of the _whole_ path string as being a regex that contains parenthesized groupings named like `:id`. That's why it doesn't work to use `^` within the parentheses (although the `$` should work at that actually is at the end of the path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how Express Router processes regular expressions, but in general, using the anchor '^' tells the regex that it should only match at the beginning of the string. So `^\\d+$` would match `35` but not `http://localhost:3000/items/35`.

If what you want is to match routes that end with a id, you shoud use `\\d+$`. '$' at the end means that there can be nothing else after the id.

Comment: Yep, taking off the `^` does it.  I can leave the `$` and all seems to work fine.