# How to redirect a route from :id to :slug

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, redirect

I had a route that initially called all blog posts by id, and now I have converted it to using the slug as the rendered URL. In my oversight, I did not think that existing links to my site would crash my app. How can I make it so that any request for my blog that was routing as `/blog/:id` to now route as `/blog/:slug`?

Comment: Do you want to handle both numbers `/blog/123` and `/blog/abc-page`, into diff middleware?

Comment: the slug is saved in my database as a string- so it would have to handle both. Essentially I just want to redirect any inbound links to my site that are following the old route to be updated to find the new slug route for the post

Comment: you could add another middleware in front (or not) which looks at `req.params.slug` if its a number do a db query to get the slug, then put it in `req.params.slug`, then in the next middleware `req.params.slug` will be the slug not the id. or do invert so slug is resolved to an id

Comment: also you could use regex like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123564/regular-expression-in-node-js-express-router if you want, then just have 2 handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is a single middleware (or if statement) as [Lawrence Cherone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661872/lawrence-cherone) mentioned in the comment.

Inside that middleware identify whether the parameter is id or slug. if it is an id, then do a database query find the slug and `return res.redirect('/blog/${slug}');`